# Protecting folders with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I met some trouble with my website (www.barbarian-strongman28.fr).

I set some url rewriting using this .htaccess which is in the main public folder of my server (called www)

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On 
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?p=404
# Pages with the PHP p= parameter
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

I have a folder called admin that I want to protect.

So I set this .htaccess

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /htdocs/admin/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user
```

I've uploaded this file in the folder that I want to protect

The trouble I have is that the website also require an authentification even if I am not in the directory protected.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Note: your `AuthGroupFile` line is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your .htaccess file is in the main directory of your server. That's your problem:

> "Also note that if you place this htaccess file in your root directory, it will password protect your entire site, which probably isn't your exact goal."
>   (from http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess3.shtml)

So the solution is simple: put the .htaccess file in the directory you want to protect. You should also make sure of a few things (though they seem ok in your script):

1. That the paths to all the files are server paths not URLs (you've done this);
2. That the .htpasswd file is in a secure location
3. That the .htpasswd file is in the format username:password, with the password encoded - here's a [tool](http://www.tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/#.U44qFRBdXg8) for creating .htpasswd files if you need it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: actualy my htaccess for the url rewritting is in the main directory. The other one is in the admin folder

Comment: Strange issue then. Here's a [guide](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess3.shtml) to htaccess password protecting that might help you.

Comment: I think I have found the trouble, I use a plugin called ckeditor, that is located in my admin when I try to display a smiley in my front office http://barbarian-strongman28.fr/admin/ckeditor/plugins/smiley/images/regular_smile.gif it call the authentification, I will remove that smiley, because, I do not know how to authorise them

Comment: ...I can't access that link because of the auth. If you want people to see it you'll need to copy it elsewhere.

Comment: If you want them to be authorised you'll have to move them out of the protected area. Perhaps into a directory called `admin-content` if you want it to be related?

Comment: Yes I will have to find an issue like that. Thank you for your help